# Errata in N. A'Campo's "Tresses, monodromie et le groupe symplectique"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, root-systems, symplectic-group

There are many small mistakes in this article. A great amount of them are concentrated in Lemma 2.

The setup for this lemma is the following. Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $n=2g+1$ or $n=2g$ a natural number greater than $3$. The symplectic group $\text{Sp}(n,R)$ has for every $\varphi\in C_g$ a root subgroup $U_\varphi$ associated to the symplectic basis $(p_1,\ldots,p_g,q_1,\ldots,q_g)$ (he could also be using the basis $(p_1,\ldots,p_g,q_g,\ldots,q_1)$, this is still a bit unclear for me). We have $U_\varphi=\{I_{2g}+t\cdot X_\varphi:t\in R\}$, where the $X_\varphi$ are given in the [Bourbaki tables](https://books.google.nl/books?id=oCO0xOzNLhAC&pg=PA205&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false).

The lemma is trying to show that for all $\varphi\in C_g\setminus\{(-1)^ke_i+(-1)^ke_j$} we either have $U_\varphi\subset G$ or $2U_\varphi:=U_\varphi\cdot U_\varphi\subset G$ where is the monodromy subgroup contained in $\text{Sp}(n,R)$ of a general family of hyperelliptic curves (this is not relevant for this post). The group $G$ is generated by the $T_i$ for $1\leq i\leq n$ and we know that $E_i^2\in G$ and $E_i^{2T}\in G$ where $1\leq i\leq g$. The $T_i$ are given in the following picture, with respect to the symplectic basis. The matrix $E_{i,j}$ is the matrix with a $1$ in entry $(i,j)$ and zeroes elsewhere.[image]

Here is my correct formulation of this Lemma:

1. $T_{2i}$ generates $U_\varphi$ for $\varphi=(-1)^i2e_i$.
2. $E_i^2$ generates $U_\varphi$ for $\varphi=(-1)^{i+1}2e_i$.
3. The subgroup $2U_\varphi$ for $\varphi=(-1)^{i+1}e_i+(-1)^{j+1}e_j$ is generated by $E_j^{(-1)^{j+1}2}E_i^{(-1)^{i+1}2}(T_{2i+1}T_{2i+2}\cdots T_{2j-1})^{-2(j-i)}$.
4. The subgroup $2U_\varphi$ for $\varphi=(-1)^ie_i+(-1)^je_j$ where $i$ and $j$ have different parity is generated by $(E_j^{(-1)^{j+1}2}E_i^{(-1)^{i+1}2})^T(T_{2i}T_{2i+1}\cdots T_{2j})^{2(j-i)+2}$.

The problem lies in item 4. The element there does not generate $2U_\varphi$ for $\varphi=(-1)^ie_i+(-1)^je_j$ where $i$ and $j$ have the same parity, but I need $2U_\varphi$ to be a subset of $G$. Has anyone ever found the correct generator of $2U_\varphi$?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author?  He is still active.

Comment: I did! Sadly, he did not reply yet...